# Dynamically Creating Cordova Builds (Android and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

**The Problem:**

In order to switch between my test/prod APIs, I've been commenting out lines depending on what build I use. Additionally, I cannot find the best way to set custom items for signing of my applications on both platforms' stores (for example: I'd like to include ".dev" in Xcode's Bundle Identifier if I'm using my test build).

---

**What I've Tried:**

The Cordova documentation talks about using build.json to declare the necessary information for signing your application. [Here for iOS](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/#signing-an-app), and [here for Android](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#signing-an-app). I tried using that (and even tried just using the flags without a file), but when I build the application, the flags dont seem to be utilized in the build folders for each platform. Here's the `build.json` I used.

```
{
    "android": {
        "debug": {
            "keystore": "../android.keystore",
            "storePassword": "android",
            "alias": "mykey1",
            "password" : "password",
            "keystoreType": ""
        ,
        "release": {
            "keystore": "../android.keystore",
            "storePassword": "",
            "alias": "mykey2",
            "password" : "password",
            "keystoreType": ""
        }
    },

    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "IDENTIFIER",
            "packageType": "debug",
            "buildFlag": [
                "PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=org.name.dev.product_name",
                "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT=YES",
                "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
                "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
            ]
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "IDENTIFIER",
            "packageType": "app-store",
            "buildFlag": [
                "PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=org.name.product_name",
                "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT=YES",
                "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
                "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here's some output from the CLI when I run `cordova run ios --target="iPad-2" --debug`:

```
Reading build config file:
    Building for iPad 2 Simulator
    Building project: /path/product_name/platforms/ios/product_name.xcworkspace
    Configuration: Debug
    Platform: emulator
Adding xcodebuildArg: PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=org.name.dev.product_name
Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /path/product_name/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = org.name.dev.product_name
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator10.3
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /path/product_name/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Build settings from configuration file '/path/product_name/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h

=== BUILD TARGET CordovaLib OF PROJECT CordovaLib WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
```

So... it LOOKS like build.json is working out, but I can't see where my xcode build arguments are being put!

Am I going about this the right way? Should I dive into hooks or `cordova-custom-config`? I'm at a loss.

---

**What I'd like to avoid...**

If it's really a must, I can try to handle the different builds with a Gulpfile, but I feel like there's a correct way to do this with Cordova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config to handle every aspect that `build.json` wasn't properly handling.